# "left homotopic" and "left homotopy" as in Quillen's book Homotopical algebra

Tags: category-theory, model-categories

I am reading Quillen's book Homotopical algebra. This is mainly about the terminology.

Fix a model category $\mathcal{C}$.

In definition $3$ (page $1.4$) Quillen defines what does it mean to say that a morphism $f:A\rightarrow B$ in $\mathcal{C}$ to be "left-homotopic to" a  morphism $g:A\rightarrow B$ in $\mathcal{C}$. It is said that, there should be an object $\widetilde{A}$ and $4$-morphisms
$$(A\xrightarrow{\partial_0} \widetilde{A}, A\xrightarrow{\partial_1} \widetilde{A}, \sigma:\widetilde{A}\rightarrow A, h:\widetilde{A}\rightarrow B)$$ such that some diagram is commutative and that $\sigma:\widetilde{A}\rightarrow A$ is a weak equivalence.

I do not have any problem with this definition.

In definition $4$ (page $1.5$) Quillen defines what it means to say "left homotopy" from $f:A\rightarrow B$ to $g:A\rightarrow B$. He says it consists of $\widetilde{A}$ as in the above definition along with the condition that $\partial_0+\partial_1:A\rightarrow \widetilde{A}$ is a cofibration.

Question:

> What is the reason to introduce two (similar sounding) terms (with almost same spelling)?

> Are there any interesting "left homotopic" situations where $\partial_0+\partial_1$ is not a cofibration (so, it does not associate to "left homotopy")?

I am aware of the notion of "homotopic" and "homotpy". I do not think the above distinction is just the same distinction between "homotopic" and "homotopy". One is a property and the other is a description of the property with certain map.

Here, we are asking for an extra condition of $\partial_0+\partial_1$ to be a cofibration.

Comment: It is because you eventually want composition to respect left homotopy classes, so you need an additional cofibrancy condition.

Comment: Also, things have been streamlined since Quillen's original treatise from 1967.  The Dwyer-Spalinski survey paper from the *Handbook* could be a "smoother" way to learn this.

Comment: @Randall I did not mean why do we ask for cofibrant condition.. I am asking why to define the former when the main thing seems to be the later.

Comment: That was Quillen's choice, I suppose.  The more modern treatments avoid this.

Comment: Ok. So, there may not be anything serious that is happening in the first definition. Is that so?

Comment: Correct........

Comment: @Randall Ok :) I will also see the Dwyer-Spalinski notes.. Thanks for the comment :)